# Postgresql not using GIN trigram index when performing non-ASCII LIKE query?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.2, explain, gin-index

### Steps to reproduce

Create database

```
CREATE DATABASE citiesdb
  WITH OWNER = citiesowner
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'C'
       LC_CTYPE = 'C'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

After creating database you can just run code from sql fiddle from the answer by Erwin https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63202/37108 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/270e2/1) or read additional info at the end of the question.

Run LIKE query with only ASCII characters

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM city WHERE other_names_lower like '%ele%';

"Bitmap Heap Scan on city  (cost=16.10..64.02 rows=13 width=147) (actual time=0.642..3.303 rows=513 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (other_names_lower ~~ '%ele%'::text)"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on other_names_lower_trgm_gin  (cost=0.00..16.10 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.486..0.486 rows=513 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (other_names_lower ~~ '%ele%'::text)"
"Total runtime: 3.439 ms"
```

Run LIKE query with non-ASCII characters

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM city WHERE (other_names_lower like '%желез%')

"Seq Scan on city  (cost=0.00..1693.53 rows=5 width=134) (actual time=33.498..58.688 rows=9 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (other_names_lower ~~ '%желез%'::text)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 46673"
"Total runtime: 58.753 ms"
```

### Question

*When searching for non-ascii text the engine is using sequential scan instead of GIN trigram index. Why is it doing that and what are alternative ways to construct the index, query or database to speed up the lookup?*

### Additional info

PostgreSQL 9.2; Windows 8 64-bit.

Part of table definition (`[...]` are other columns).

`CREATE TABLE city ([...] other_names_lower text [...]) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );`

Column other_names_lower contains different names for cities. Rows contain Chinese, Polish, Russian and other character ranges.

Index creation code

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX other_names_lower_trgm_gin
  ON city
  USING gin
  (other_names_lower gin_trgm_ops);
```

Other settings - query suggested by Daniel Vérité in the comment

```
select name, source, setting from pg_settings where source <> 'default' and source <> 'override';

"application_name";"client";"pgAdmin III - Narz??dzie Zapytania"
"bytea_output";"session";"escape"
"client_encoding";"session";"UNICODE"
"client_min_messages";"session";"notice"
"DateStyle";"session";"ISO, YMD"
"default_text_search_config";"configuration file";"pg_catalog.simple"
"enable_seqscan";"session";"on"
"lc_messages";"configuration file";"en_US.UTF-8"
"lc_monetary";"configuration file";"Polish_Poland.1250"
"lc_numeric";"configuration file";"Polish_Poland.1250"
"lc_time";"configuration file";"Polish_Poland.1250"
"listen_addresses";"configuration file";"*"
"log_destination";"configuration file";"stderr"
"log_line_prefix";"configuration file";"%t "
"log_statement";"configuration file";"all"
"log_timezone";"configuration file";"Europe/Sarajevo"
"logging_collector";"configuration file";"on"
"max_connections";"configuration file";"100"
"max_stack_depth";"environment variable";"2048"
"port";"configuration file";"5432"
"shared_buffers";"configuration file";"4096"
"TimeZone";"configuration file";"Europe/Sarajevo"
```

Comment: I don't see the table definition in your question: what you get with `\d city` in `psql`. And the setting for `LC_COLLATE` is also the *default*, i.e. the `COLLATION` for the index?

Comment: That should go into your question. Use `edit` above.

Comment: I didn't really write `COLLATE pg_catalog."default"` when creating index, I guess it is just a thing added implicitly by pgAdmin or the engine...

Comment: That's right. That's what pgAdmin prints if the collation of the column agrees with the default. But the column in the table might be defined otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created your scenario with `COLLATE = "C"`, and both queries use a bitmap index scan index on `other_names_lower_trgm_gin` as expected.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/270e2/1) with a table of ~ 10k rows, Postgres 9.2.4, `COLLATE = "C"`.

There is probably something wrong in your setup that is *not* in your question.
 Run (takes some time for big tables and an exclusive lock!):

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE city;
```

And try again ...

Comment: VACUUM took 7250 ms (only ~50k rows); no problem with the lock, it's a dev machine; still seq scan though with the non-ascii version; it's nice to see that the non-ascii index search can work (because the fiddle works)

Comment: I executed all DDL from the fiddle (only changed table and index name) on my database; result: still index scan with `'%ele%'` (2.4 ms) and seq scan with `'%желез%'` (67.9 ms) - so the problem seems to be with the database, not with table or index - so I'll add database creation code to the question

Comment: See if you have non-standard cost settings with `select name,source,setting from pg_settings where source<>'default' and source<>'override';`

Comment: Added  @DanielVérité 's query result at the end of the question

Comment: @user44 I'm confused, you've marked this as the answer but in the comment above you've said it didn't solve the non-ascii use-case. Can you clarify how you solved this?

Comment: I am seeing something similar with Japanese characters. The cost of index scan seems to be much higher then for ascii terms with the same number of matching rows...