# Postgresql strange behavior with non-ascii characters with triagram index present

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, gist-index, gin-index

I see some strange behavior when using either `gin_trgm_ops` or `gist_trgm_ops` indexes. There seems to be quite a difference in plans when using say `ILIKE` or `~` and search for ascii phrases vs multi-byte char phrases. As if there is higher cost when the operand is a non-ascii operand.

Is what I am seeing expected? What is the reason for it?

I tried it on Postgreql 12 and 13 latest of each.

Here is a scenario:

```
CREATE DATABASE postgres
    WITH
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    IS_TEMPLATE = False;

-- snip

CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    label varchar
);

-- insert 1m rows

VACUUM ANALYZE test_table;
```

In the data set I have 10 labels containing `'acl'` and 10 containing `'定す'`.

When using GIN index

```
CREATE INDEX test_table_label_gin_idx
    ON test_table USING gin
    (label gin_trgm_ops);
```

I see the following.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE label ILIKE '%定す%' LIMIT 100;

Limit  (cost=1000.00..16573.18 rows=100 width=52) (actual time=392.153..395.095 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..16728.91 rows=101 width=52) (actual time=392.135..394.830 rows=10 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test_table  (cost=0.00..15718.81 rows=42 width=52) (actual time=382.922..388.082 rows=3 loops=3)
              Filter: ((label)::text ~~* '%定す%'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 338417
Planning Time: 0.656 ms
Execution Time: 395.233 ms


EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE label ILIKE '%acl%' LIMIT 100;

Limit  (cost=28.78..400.51 rows=100 width=52) (actual time=0.072..0.406 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_table  (cost=28.78..404.23 rows=101 width=52) (actual time=0.053..0.197 rows=10 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((label)::text ~~* '%acl%'::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=10
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_table_label_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..28.76 rows=101 width=0) (actual time=0.025..0.034 rows=10 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((label)::text ~~* '%acl%'::text)
Planning Time: 0.231 ms
Execution Time: 0.542 ms
```

With GIST

```
DROP INDEX test_table_label_gin_idx;

CREATE INDEX test_table_label_gist_idx
    ON test_table USING gist
    (label gist_trgm_ops);
```

I see

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE label ILIKE '%定す%' LIMIT 100;

Limit  (cost=13.19..384.92 rows=100 width=52) (actual time=303.772..1557.498 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_table  (cost=13.19..388.64 rows=101 width=52) (actual time=303.752..1557.286 rows=10 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((label)::text ~~* '%定す%'::text)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1015250
        Heap Blocks: exact=10431
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_table_label_gist_idx  (cost=0.00..13.17 rows=101 width=0) (actual time=301.046..301.053 rows=1015260 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((label)::text ~~* '%定す%'::text)
Planning Time: 0.215 ms
Execution Time: 1557.643 ms


EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE label ILIKE '%acl%' LIMIT 100;

Limit  (cost=13.19..384.92 rows=100 width=52) (actual time=257.385..257.751 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_table  (cost=13.19..388.64 rows=101 width=52) (actual time=257.366..257.551 rows=10 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((label)::text ~~* '%acl%'::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=10
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_table_label_gist_idx  (cost=0.00..13.17 rows=101 width=0) (actual time=257.319..257.328 rows=10 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((label)::text ~~* '%acl%'::text)
Planning Time: 0.377 ms
Execution Time: 257.948 ms
```

Just changing the the characters of the operand change the plan quite a lot.

**Edit**

```
SELECT show_trgm('定す');

"{0x145ed8,0x6628fa,0x6cb12d}"

SELECT encode('定す', 'escape')

\345\256\232\343\201\231
```

This issue seems similar [Postgresql not using GIN trigram index when performing non-ASCII LIKE query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63193/postgresql-not-using-gin-trigram-index-when-performing-non-ascii-like-query)

Comment: Thank you, I added `show_trgm` output. How do I convert that into `E'\u7777'` notation?

Comment: `SELECT encode('定す', 'escape')` outputs `\345\256\232\343\201\231`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your query has no trigrams in it.  The way that pg_trgm uses hashing to represent wide characters make this hard to see just based on your show_trgm output, but what we can see is the output only has three trigrams in it.  But none of those trigrams are usable in the context of ILIKE.  If we look instead at the output of `show_trgm('ab')`, we see that it as well has three trigrams:

```
{"  a"," ab","ab "}
```

But notice that all three of them have at least one space in them, and those ones are not usable for the pattern side of the ILIKE. (That is not a blanket rule.  If the pattern actually had spaces or punctuation in it, then some trigrams that contained spaces would be usable; it is just ones that contain "artificial" spaces that are not usable.)

If we do the same with 'acl', we see that it has 4 trigrams, one of which has no spaces and so is usable.

```
{"  a"," ac",acl,"cl "}
```

If you were to repeat your query with the string '%ab%' I think you would find that that one too has a high cost estimate and chooses the "wrong" query plan.  Because the planner extracts the usable trigrams before estimating and choosing the plan, sees that there will be zero of them, and knows that that is going to be horrible for performance.

I think that the trigram approach really isn't very suitable for logographic languages.  But I don't know what the alternative is.

Comment: For an alternative, what do you think about what this blog proposes for Chinese character support for version prior to 9.3 https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/performance-optimization-of-fuzzy-queries-for-chinese-characters-using-postgresql-trgm_595634 (Support for Chinese Characters (For Versions Prior to 9.3)). If the indexed text was lower-cased before encoding, it could support of mix of characters. In this case `'定す'` would become `e5ae9ae38199`.

Comment: That seems plausible for getting the index to be selective.  Not knowing Chinese, I can't evaluate how intuitive the results would be.

Comment: Btw, this solution from alibabacloud above does work and works better for search strings 1-2 chars long, but it's not that good for everything else. Also the index is 40% larger. We ended up just using it for such short string searches as they are important for our customer.